# Why is current status of job is UNKNOWN while executing Spring batch using AsycnTaskExecutor

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I was launching job using JobOperator having taskExecutor as AsyncTaskExecutor so that job can run in background. In the documentation Spring Batch, it is also given that when we execute job like this, progress will be unknown.

Ideally it should be in progress, as job is running in background. So by it in unknown? What is its significance?

Comment: How are you checking the status of the job?  When you launch the job asynchronously the JobExecution object you get back can't possibly know about the status of the job since it is happening in another thread.  If you want to get the actual status you need to get a new instance of the JobExecution from the JobRepository.

Comment: Batch can go up for typically 1-2 hours also. I want an endpoint to check its status. But all asycn jobs are having their status as UNKNOWS. I know that is in different thread. But checking database metadata tables ideally should have identical results, don't you think so? But here comes UNKNOWN in picture.Why?

Comment: How are you retrieving the status?  Are you querying the BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION table directly, or are you going through the JobRepository?

Comment: Yes, I’m using JobRepository to get the current status

Comment: Implement your own JobExplorer or custom DAO to fetch the status from BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.   A simple select from the status column can get you that information.

Comment: Yes. I'm doing the same. But status is unknown when i launch an Async job. If its an normal job, then its running